# how to zoom svg semantic graph when the mouse is under svg instead of node

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on collapsible tree graph zoom. Whenever i wanna zoom i have to keep mouse pointer on node(circle) then only i am able to do zoom in and zoom out. But it should be able to that when mouse is any where in graph.

zoom function call is following:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1,8]).on("zoom",zoom));
```

I am following this example link for zoom in and zoom out : http://jsfiddle.net/6kEpp/37/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Do you want to zoom with the cursor over a node or anywhere in the graph?

Comment: So that's a normal zoom behaviour?

Comment: Actually above code working on zoom with the cursor over a node. But i'm looking for anywhere in graph.

Comment: It works if you prevent the default on double click and transform the entire SVG -- http://jsfiddle.net/6kEpp/38/. However, to do this properly you would have to detect yourself whether a click or double click is made on a node.

Comment: Yes. SVG Semantic zoom.

Comment: You can add a background rectangle to the group, and add the nodes over it. This way, the zoom will be always applied.

Comment: Its working exactlly i have applied background rectangle to the group. Thanks a lot Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

Just append rectangle to the SVG that's it.

```
svg.append('svg:rect')
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('fill', 'white');
```